# Sql for xml: how to avoid a specific field is output as attribute?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, for-xml

The stating point for this qusetion is [Control on XML elements nesting using FOR XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877161/control-on-xml-elements-nesting-using-for-xml)

I would like that the output changes from

```
<security AccessLevel="5" />
```

to

```
<security>5<security/>
```

Basically instead of displaying `AccessLevel` as attribute I would like its value becomes the value of the element `security`.
How to achieve such a result.
I copy here the example from the linked post for clarity:

```
DECLARE @Employees table(  
    EmpID int NOT NULL,  
    Name nvarchar(50),  
    Surname nvarchar(50),  
    DateOfBirth date,
    DepartmentID int,
    AccessLevel int);
insert into  @Employees    values ('1', 'John','Doe','1980-01-31',100,5)
insert into  @Employees    values ('2', 'Mary','Rose','1971-02-27',102,3)
insert into  @Employees    values ('3', 'Luke','Perry','1995-12-01',104,1)

select
  employee.Name,
  employee.Surname,
  employee.DateOfBirth,
  department.DepartmentID, 
  security.AccessLevel  -- THIS IS THE INVOLVED FIELD
from @Employees employee
join @Employees department on department.DepartmentID = employee.DepartmentID
join @Employees security on security.AccessLevel = employee.AccessLevel
for xml auto
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using `@` in alias name to generate the `attributes` in `xml`. To get the `accesslevel` as element just don't add `@` to alias name

Something like this

```
SELECT NAME         AS [@Name],
       Surname      AS [@Surname],
       DateOfBirth  AS [@DateOfBirth],
       DepartmentID AS [department/@DepartmentID],
       AccessLevel  AS [department/security]
FROM   @Employees
FOR xml path('employee')
```

**Result:**

```
<employee Name="John" Surname="Doe" DateOfBirth="1980-01-31">
  <department DepartmentID="100">
    <security>5</security>
  </department>
</employee>
<employee Name="Mary" Surname="Rose" DateOfBirth="1971-02-27">
  <department DepartmentID="102">
    <security>3</security>
  </department>
</employee>
<employee Name="Luke" Surname="Perry" DateOfBirth="1995-12-01">
  <department DepartmentID="104">
    <security>1</security>
  </department>
</employee>
```