# How to add a wrapping element in a for xml select?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, for-xml

I would like to improve my example made in [Control on XML elements nesting using FOR XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877161/control-on-xml-elements-nesting-using-for-xml)

I would like to add an element that wraps all (in this example the information is about the company.)

DATA:

```
DECLARE @Employees table(
    CompanyID int,
    companyDescr nvarchar(100)  ,
    EmpID int NOT NULL,  
    Name nvarchar(50),  
    Surname nvarchar(50),  
    DateOfBirth date,
    DepartmentID int,
    AccessLevel int);
insert into  @Employees    values (1,'ACME','1', 'John','Doe','1980-01-31',100,5)
insert into  @Employees    values (1,'ACME', '2', 'Mary','Rose','1971-02-27',102,3)
insert into  @Employees    values (1,'ACME', '3', 'Luke','Perry','1995-12-01',104,1)
```

Expected Result:

```
<company companyID="1">
    <employee Name="John" Surname="Doe" DateOfBirth="1980-01-31">
      <department DepartmentID="100">
        <security>
          <AccessLevel>5</AccessLevel>
        </security>
      </department>
    </employee>
    <employee Name="Mary" Surname="Rose" DateOfBirth="1971-02-27">
      <department DepartmentID="102">
        <security>
          <AccessLevel>3</AccessLevel>
        </security>
      </department>
    </employee>
    <employee Name="Luke" Surname="Perry" DateOfBirth="1995-12-01">
      <department DepartmentID="104">
        <security>
          <AccessLevel>1</AccessLevel>
        </security>
      </department>
    </employee>
</company>
```

How to query the `@employees` table to obtain the result?

The only way I found is to save the query of the linked question into a string variable and manually append data before and after it.

Is it possible to achieve the result with a query?

Answer (score 0):

You can correlate a subquery for on companyId like this:

```
select
    companyid as "@companyID",
    cast((
        select name as "@Name",
            surname as "@Surname",
            dateofbirth as "@DateOfBirth",
            departmentid as "department/@departmentID",
            accesslevel as "department/security/AccessLevel"
        from @employees e2
        where e2.companyid = e1.companyid
        for xml path('employee')
    ) as xml)
from @employees e1
group by companyid for xml path('company');
```

Produces:

```
<company companyID="1">
  <employee Name="John" Surname="Doe" DateOfBirth="1980-01-31">
    <department departmentID="100">
      <security>
        <AccessLevel>5</AccessLevel>
      </security>
    </department>
  </employee>
  <employee Name="Mary" Surname="Rose" DateOfBirth="1971-02-27">
    <department departmentID="102">
      <security>
        <AccessLevel>3</AccessLevel>
      </security>
    </department>
  </employee>
  <employee Name="Luke" Surname="Perry" DateOfBirth="1995-12-01">
    <department departmentID="104">
      <security>
        <AccessLevel>1</AccessLevel>
      </security>
    </department>
  </employee>
</company>
```